# Will games played with an EA Play subscription drop Steam Trading Cards?

Tags: steam, ea-play

Some EA games present on [EA Play](https://store.steampowered.com/subscriptions/ea) like Battlefield 4 say that they drop Stream Trading Cards.

Will the games drop the Trading Cards if they have been accessed via the EA Play Subscription or would I need to actually purchase the game?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EA Access games are exempt from Steam Trading Card drops. See this two examples with no playtime and a bit of playtime with STAR WARS Jedi: Fallen Order and Need for Speed Rivals respectively.

[image]
[image]